# How can I localize a element thats change constantily a number in their ID in Selenium WebDriver with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to find a element in a page that posses a considerable number of the same element, the difference between the elements is one ID with numbers in the final of the name. for example:

The only one visible when the page is loaded: limit_arrown_btn_3201
But this number in the end of the ID changes when some action are aplicated in the system.Because of that I dont have a way to maping the elements to send the click event, because whent the element is changed the last numbers of ID is alterated, crashing my scripts...

I have tried to use CssSelector, but all another caracteristics like Names and Classes is exactly the same.

Did some one haved experienced the same situation and could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: may be X-path will do the job here for you

Comment: can you share the html code for the same. it may help to solve it better way.

Comment: @Murthi this may be useful https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath

Comment: @ameyadeshpande I am not op here

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial id, contains `*=` or start with `^=`

```
By.CssSelector([id*='limit_arrown_btn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

At work, we run into this situation all the time. For us, this usually happens as a result of extJS dynamically renaming elements on us. To get around it, I use xpath and usually move up the DOM a few levels to find a unique element. Then, with the console open (Chrome is my browser of choice here), I click on and off the element that is dynamically changing. Chrome will highlight what attributes are changing when this happens. This way, you can see what does and does not change and tailor your xpath to match. For instance, we have an application that generates tables using randomly generated IDs. I built a utility class in which you pass in a WebElement that represents the whole table wrapper (header, body, footer, etc.) and a String value of the header column that you want to look at. From that, I get the dynamic ID for the column of the table: (Forgive the examples, as they are in Java and not C#)

```
public String getGridColumnFromTable(WebElement tableDivElement, String headerColumn) {
    WebElement newElement = waitUntilElementIsClickable(tableDivElement);
    WebElement contextContainer = null;

    String headerXPath = ".//child::div[contains(@id,'headercontainer')]/child::div/child::div/child::div/child::div/span[.='" + headerColumn + "']";
    WebElement headerGridColumn = newElement.findElement(By.xpath(headerXPath));
    waitUntilElementIsClickable(headerGridColumn);
    String contextContainerXpath = ".//parent::div/parent::div";
    contextContainer = headerGridColumn.findElement(By.xpath(contextContainerXpath));

    String gridColumnID = contextContainer.getAttribute("id");
    waitForPostBack();
    return gridColumnID;
}
```

Once I have that dynamic gridColumnID, I use that to tie all the other functions to it, like this:

```
public String getCellTextInTableByRowAndColumnName(WebElement tableDivElement, int rowNumber, String headerColumn) {
    WebElement newElement = waitUntilElementIsClickable(tableDivElement);
    String tableGridColumnId = getGridColumnFromTable(newElement, headerColumn);
    return newElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr[contains(@data-recordindex, '" + rowNumber + "')]/td[contains(@class, '" + tableGridColumnId + "')]//div")).getText();
}
```

While this example may be a bit foreign to you, since your project is most likely very different, it does show how to work around the problem by traversing the DOM to find the element you're after.

If you have a few html snippets you could post, it would be most helpful in tailoring an answer.